# How can i use OSMDROID Polyline in android

Tags: android, android-studio, maps, osmdroid

```
GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(104.9274702345929, -78.8899208239701);
GeoPoint endPoint = new GeoPoint(102.946749865264,-78.8935274008143);

RoadManager roadManager = new OSRMRoadManager();
ArrayList<GeoPoint> waypoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
waypoints.add(startPoint);
waypoints.add(endPoint);

Road road = roadManager.getRoad(waypoints);
Polyline roadOverlay = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road, this);
map.getOverlays().add(roadOverlay);
map.invalidate();
```

I cant draw polyline in mapView,I have a problem when I run this code and I see the error in Polyline code line,
like this:
Incompatible types.
Required:
org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Polyline
Found:
org.osmdroid.views.overlay.PathOverla

Answer (score 1):

You are using an old version of the osmbonuspack library.

A return type of the method `RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road, this)` was  `PathOverlay` up to the versions ~4.3, but since than it returns `Polyline`. Current version is (at the time of writing) 6.5.2, so you somehow included quite obsolete version.

Follow this guide in order to use the latest version: https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/HowToInclude